# "getContext is not a function" when using variable for element selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
<div id="canvasContainer">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="450" width="650"></canvas>
</div>
```

and:

```
var myCanvas = $("#myCanvas");
var myCanvasContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

yet I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: myCanvas.getContext is not a function

when the page is loaded.

When I try something like:

```
myCanvas.click (function() {
    console.log("You clicked the canvas");
});
```

the reference to `myCanvas` works perfectly. What gives?

Comment: `myCanvas` in your code is a jQueery object, not a DOM element ...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`getContext` is not a part of jQuery library, it's a part of WebAPI. You have to reference the raw DOM Node object instead of jQuery wrapper:

```
var myCanvas = $("#myCanvas");
var myCanvasContext = myCanvas[0].getContext("2d");
```

(what `[0]` does is it references the underlying DOM Node that jQuery wrapper hides from you).

---

Your "click" example works, because `element.click` (in your case) is actually a part of jQuery library API: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 3):

`myCanvas` in your code is a jQuery object, not a DOM element ...

use the following code instead

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var myCanvasContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

of course, then `myCanvas.click(...)` wont work, but you can always do

```
$(myCanvas).click(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the html5 canvas element instead of creating an element using id.
Eg. `<canvas></canvas>`

```
var canvas  = document.getElementById("canvas");
            context     = canvas.getContext('2d');

            base_image = new Image();
            base_image.src = imageUrl;
            base_image.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

`var myCanvas = $("#myCanvas");`get a JQuery Object，you need to do like this

```
var myCanvasContext = myCanvas[0].getContext("2d");
```

myCanvas[0] is a DOM Object,

Suggest that you express jquery object like this

```
var $myCanvas = $("#myCanvas")
```

Comment: I agree, `$` prefix for jQuery result objects should be made mandatory

Comment: I always used to use the `$` prefix for variables that refer to jQuery objects, and I do still sometimes do it in answers I post to Stack Overflow because some people seem to expect it, especially if there is another variable referencing a DOM object, but I don't do it in my own code at all anymore. I figure I get by just fine without using Hungarian notation for any *other* data types, so why make an exception specifically for jQuery objects?

Comment: For  example ,I'm chinese,I use English to communicate with you, although this will let me spend some time。

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same error because i was using a modal, the dom wasn't ready to get my canvas !
So i did this :

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvasID');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        // ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done as:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```